# The tasks items of Chrome shortcut on taskbar don't work

Tags: windows, google-chrome, taskbar

It appears after i reset my windows in settings.
They are actually "new window" and "New Incognito window", but it seems that they could not be found.

How to fix or just remove such items? I have already reinstalled Chrome and reboot Windows.

[image: Chrome on taskbar]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, did you try readding the icon? Did you mess with Chrome files/registry before this started happening?

Comment: @Destroy666 I reset windows to free disk space

Comment: Reset in what way exactly? Please edit 1st post with any additional info.

Comment: Is there policy on your computer, applied by someone else, such as a school or employer, that prevents incognito mode or the like?

Comment: @Destroy666 windows settings -> system -> recovery -> reset. No more useful info i can provide now.

Comment: @music2myear There may not be. It was everything normal before i reset my windows.

Comment: You could try full uninstall with leftover removal with e.g. BCUninstaller, then reinstall.  But you haven't answered if you tried unpinning and pinning. I would recommend answering **accurately** as the question is close to being closed for missing details.